# Is there a way to set column height (or alternatively, convert a standard report to a mail label)?

Tags: crystal-reports, multiple-columns

I'm using Crystal Reports to create a document with one header and two columns of detail per page. What I want is that every page would be like this:

```
-----------------------
|   Group Header      |
|_____________________|
Details 1  | Details 4
Details 2  | Details 5
Details 3  | Details 6
----------------------
|   Group Footer      |
|_____________________|
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
-----------------------
|   Group Header      |
|_____________________|
Details 1  
Details 2  
Details 3  
Details 4
Details 5
Details 6
----------------------
|   Group Footer      |
|_____________________|
```

The footer even gets pushed down to the next page if there are too many records.

I already set the details section to "Format with multiple columns", but didn't format groups by columns. This is because I want each group to fill a whole page, and have only one header that spans the entire width of the page. The details width is only 3.6 in, the page is 8.5 inches with 0.5 in left margin, 0.3 right margin, so I don't think it's the measurements. I set the page footer to print at the bottom of the page, but that only prints the footer at the end of the next page.

What I'm looking for, basically, is something to stop the details from printing downwards and force it to go to the next column. I can't set the data height in the Section Expert (the field's disabled), and I read elsewhere that I could create a mail label instead, but that would mean creating the report all over again (something I'd prefer not to do, as there are too many elements in the report).

---

Update:
It's definitely not the measurements (data width and distance between columns), as tested. Still struggling with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it myself, but not through using mail labels. In fact I couldn't get it to work with mail labels.

I moved the Group header/footer to the Page header/footer, and then suppressed both (empty) group header and footer. The group footer I set to "New page after". Ticked "Format Groups with multiple column", and adjusted the section heights and data heights to fit on one page.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you select "Across then Down" in details section layout tab? Will you get next layout:

```
-----------------------
|   Group Header      |
|_____________________|
Details 1  | Details 2
Details 3  | Details 4
Details 5  | Details 6
----------------------
|   Group Footer      |
|_____________________|
```

If not, then you details section is too wide or horizontal gap between sections is too big.

Comment: Tried Across then Down and yes, it displays as you mentioned.